# How to distribute iPad App to Customer (B2B) with an iOS enterprise account

Tags: ios, ipad, enterprise-distribution

My company has an iOS Enterprise Account to distribute In-House Apps. Now we want to develop an app for a customer. The question is: How to deploy the app to the customer's employee's devices? I heard about a "B2B Program", but I wasn't able to find any further details how to deploy to a special Business Store.

I know that there are a lot of discussion about this topic on the net, but I missed the fine details how the process is working in detail.

So what possibilities we have to get the app installed on the customer's employee's iPads?

EDIT: I don't want to invite beta testers or anything similar. I need an official way to install the app on the devices of the customers employees.

Comment: As far as I remember, you can't use your enterprise to deploy on devices that doesn't belong to your company. You should read the agreement of your enterprise account.

Comment: I was afraid that this is the matter. So besides our enterprise account, is there anything else that we can do or that the customer must do in order to be able to install the app on their devices?

Comment: Depends, if you want that the app will not be available on the appstore your customer should enroll an enterprise account for itself and you can manage it just by adding yourself as administrator. The distribution could be easily done by OTA.

Comment: Technically with your enterprise account you can distribute the app using OTA, but is a violation of the Apple agreement.

Answer (score 2):

Another faster solution then testflightapp is diawi.com.
The link doesn't hold forever but it takes a few seconds to generate a download link.
You either use an archived IPA or a zipped .app , drag it to the relevant part of the site and it generates a download link for you.

We have been using this with a lot of customers with great success.
Just remember - the link is temporary.

Alternatively you can build a simple web page around the IPA file on a server you own (look at the generated diawi page for reference of the tags and info used).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try **OTA Distribution process**, for more details go through this [link](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air).

Here download link is permanent and you don't need to use any third party tool.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but isn't this method only valid for beta users (e.g. you must add each UUID of the devices to your developer program and you have the 100 devices limit)?

Comment: As far as i know when you create ipa with enterprise distribution profile there is no restriction of number of user.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a Mobile Distribution Platform like MobileIron?

http://www.mobileiron.com

A few clients at my work use them and their services are pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this for a client now. B2B is, I think, not what you want. Enterprise distribution is intended, by Apple, for in-house distribution. 'In-house' extends as far as out-of-house reps, and even independent contractors who use your client's in-house business app.

Your client should purchase his own Enterprise Developer's certificate, or ask you to purchase one for him. Use that certificate and associated provisioning profile to publish the app (in the usual way using the 'Ad-Hoc' distribution type). Then deploy over-the-air.